# I want to make 3 div's display in the same row with min-width of screen is 992px

Tags: layout, media-queries, desktop

I have added float and media query but my code does not seem to work for 992 and above.Please let me know what am missing.

https://jsfiddle.net/ju1gpmeL/

```
@media(min-width: 992px){
#d1{
    float: left;
    width:32%;
}

#d2{
    float: left;
    width: 32%;
}
#d3{
    float: left;
    width: 32%;

}
```

}

Comment: maybe try change the width of the divs inside your @media like `width: 31%;` ?

Comment: 33%, 33%, 34% will work.

Comment: @claudios Doing that is working.But is leaving extra space behind 3rd div.

Comment: @Harminder That percentage split is not working

Comment: You also have fixed width left and right margin of 10 px. I removed margin and all three DIVs are in the same row. 
 
jsfiddle.net/ju1gpmeL/11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media(min-width: 992px){
#d1{
    float: left;
    width:33%;
}

#d2{
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}
#d3{
    float: left;
    width: 33%;

}

}
```

Comment: Divs aren't equal in this one

Comment: The above code is pushing the 3rd div completely to the next line

Comment: I tested in Firefox and IE all three div are displayed in one line as long as you have total pixels more than 992. As soon as you reduce the width, all three dives are displayed in three different lines.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!